# Heroku errors when deploying node-react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm, mongoose

I am deploying a fullstack react/express app to Heroku, it has managed to deploy. There are multiple errors in the Heroku logs which I have cannot seem to understand/figure out. I also have a Procfile with `web: node server.js`

I have tried to clear cache - delete node_modules and package.json then npm install again but this has not made a difference.

Heroku Logs

```
2020-11-15T13:08:12.713935+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2020-11-15T13:08:12.713935+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
2020-11-15T13:08:12.713935+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2020-11-15T13:08:12.783289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-15T13:08:12.818062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-15T13:08:12.826070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-15T13:08:21.448256+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324135+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:669
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324170+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324175+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324175+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324180+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324185+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:669:11)
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324185+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:342:10
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324190+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:9:12)
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324190+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10)
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324190+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:18:10)
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324191+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324191+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324191+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324191+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324192+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
2020-11-15T13:08:24.324196+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2020-11-15T13:08:24.418110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-15T13:08:24.454083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-15T13:23:24.786742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-journey-43421.herokuapp.com request_id=aa6c54d3-cfe3-4f74-b4c5-93018f00ba97 fwd="84.9.66.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-15T13:23:26.240301+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-journey-43421.herokuapp.com request_id=ec07ad1c-091f-4e53-b50d-9632b66dd2d4 fwd="84.9.66.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-15T13:27:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user peterjameslewis4@hotmail.com
2020-11-15T13:29:08.458958+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 12d81f3b by user peterjameslewis4@hotmail.com
2020-11-15T13:29:08.458958+00:00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user peterjameslewis4@hotmail.com
2020-11-15T13:29:08.625747+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-15T13:29:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-11-15T13:29:17.927953+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-11-15T13:29:20.083139+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-15T13:29:20.083155+00:00 app[web.1]: > movie-database@1.0.0 start /app
2020-11-15T13:29:20.083155+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-11-15T13:29:20.083155+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795200+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:669
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795248+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795250+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795250+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795251+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795252+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:669:11)
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795254+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:342:10
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795254+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:9:12)
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795255+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10)
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795255+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:18:10)
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795255+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795256+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795256+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795256+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795257+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
2020-11-15T13:29:20.795258+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2020-11-15T13:29:20.810114+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-11-15T13:29:20.810451+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-11-15T13:29:20.817598+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! movie-database@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-11-15T13:29:20.817850+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-11-15T13:29:20.818099+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-11-15T13:29:20.818312+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the movie-database@1.0.0 start script.
2020-11-15T13:29:20.818490+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-11-15T13:29:20.827750+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-15T13:29:20.828041+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-11-15T13:29:20.828210+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-11-15T13_29_20_819Z-debug.log
2020-11-15T13:29:20.877545+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-15T13:29:20.913439+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-15T13:29:20.917070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-15T13:29:33.460653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-11-15T13:29:36.844587+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-15T13:29:36.844630+00:00 app[web.1]: > movie-database@1.0.0 start /app
2020-11-15T13:29:36.844631+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-11-15T13:29:36.844631+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011159+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:669
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011219+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011220+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011220+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011224+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011224+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:669:11)
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011225+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:342:10
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011226+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:9:12)
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011226+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10)
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011226+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:18:10)
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011227+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011227+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011227+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011228+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011228+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
2020-11-15T13:29:38.011229+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2020-11-15T13:29:38.046555+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-11-15T13:29:38.047758+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-11-15T13:29:38.059446+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! movie-database@1.0.0 start: node server.js
2020-11-15T13:29:38.059681+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-11-15T13:29:38.059955+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-11-15T13:29:38.060192+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the movie-database@1.0.0 start script.
2020-11-15T13:29:38.060432+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-11-15T13:29:38.096793+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-15T13:29:38.097273+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-11-15T13:29:38.097587+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-11-15T13_29_38_061Z-debug.log
2020-11-15T13:29:38.193702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-15T13:29:38.242866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


// Auth Routes
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

dotenv.config();

//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    () => console.log('connected to DB!')
);

// Serve static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build/')));

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// Put all API endpoints under '/api'
app.use('/api', authRoute)


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'));
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "movie-database",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Small application created with React.js, react router and the movie database to showcase all latest, upcoming and most popular movies.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "joi": "^17.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.12",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "password-generator": "^2.3.2",
    "serve": "^11.3.2"
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Go to settings in heroku, there you will find reveal vars, add a variable for your database, as- DB_CONNECT, Give it value of your database uri

Comment: OMG! you're amazing! haha i've been stuck on this bloody issue for days! thank you so much!

Comment: HaHa, it is very common problem,when deploying to cloud, one always need to set the env variables